# DataGridView null при чтение данных

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Программка многопоточно вставляет / забирает данные из ячеек таблицы.
И есть одно узкое место, поток вставляет данные в ячейку и он же через какое то количество мс забирает эти вставленные данные.

И тут бывает вылетает исключение - якобы там null, ну т.е. null - я думал меня спасёт Thread.Sleep(1000), но если я правильно понял - подобное ожидание не спасёт оно тупо вешает всё и отрисовке не поможет.

Я ещё умудрился над этим Thread.Sleep(1000) поставить метку и в случае исключения переходить туда с помощью goto - ну и конечно же у меня всё зациклилось.

Правильно я понимаю ? Они ещё не успели каким то образом зарегистрироваться в ячейке, а я пытаюсь их уже забрать ?

Как всё же получить такие данные ?

Так заливаю:

```
BeginInvoke(new Delegate(() => { dataGridView["column1", nomStroki].Value = value; }));
```

И в другом методе этого же потока забираю:

```
if (dataGridView["column1", nomStroki].Value.ToString() == "Нет данных")
```

NullReferenceException

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1. Заменить `BeginInvoke` на `Invoke`. 2. Не работать с графическими контролами напрямую, а использовать какую-либо коллекцию для хранения данных. (Эту коллекцию прибиндить к GUI).

Comment: _в другом методе_ - имелось в виду _в другом месте_?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov как бы да, но внутри этого потока

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov как бы записывать где то промежуточно ? и оттуда брать и оттуда отрисовывать ?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Посмотрите пожалуйста - дайте комментарий - делаю как вы сказали https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1045972/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%83-%d1%81-datagridview?noredirect=1#comment1785686_1045972