# Как правильно реализовать работу с DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Ранее я сразу использовал DataGridView как место для хранения данных - туда записывал и оттуда забирал. Но один хороший человек, подсказал что это неправильно и нужно использовать какой то промежуточное место для хранения, а оттуда уже отображать в DataGridView и т.д. (Если я правильно понял)

Но вот есть такой момент, я подумал - что могу использовать двумерный массив например, но как его привязать к DataGridView и отображать в реальном времени изменённые данные ?

Я заранее знаю сколько у меня будет стобцов / строк и их количество не изменяемое.

Или для этого нужно использовать только List ? Которыми я ещё не овладел xD

**UPD:**
Немного разобрался как работают коллекции и с привязкой к `DataGridView`
Но есть вопрос - каждый раз если я изменил какое то значение в коллекции - мне нужно каждый раз использовать `bindingSource.ResetItem` ? Или есть что то встроенное ? Типа задал `True` и само обновляется ? И могут ли быть проблемы с bindingSource.ResetItem если я вызываю его из другого потока ?

```
    private void ChangeItemVin(int val, string text)
    {
        list[val].Vin = text;
        bindingSource.ResetItem(val);
    }
```

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/datagridview

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо! Обновил вопрос после UPD - можете подсказать ?

Comment: я таких деталей не помню уже, много лет не работал с winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простейший пример, будет считать асинхронно числа фибоначчи.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сначала создадим класс модели, реализующий `INotifyPropertyChanged` в свойстве, которое
будем изменять значение программно будем вызывать событие `PropertyChanged` с тем, чтоб обновить отображаемое значение в DGV.

```
class Number : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public int InputValue { get; private set; }

    private int _OutputValue;
    public int OutputValue
    {
        get => _OutputValue;
        set
        {
            _OutputValue = value;
            //оповещаем, что значение свойства изменилось
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(OutputValue)));
        }
    }

    public Number(int id, int value)
    {
        Id = id;
        InputValue = value;
    }
}
```

Далее код формы.
Используем в качестве источника данных для DGV `BindingList<T>`.

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    //источник данных для DGV
    private BindingList<Number> _blNumbers;

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Пример";
        //установки привязок
        SetBindings();

        _button.Click += Button_Click;
        this.Load += FormMain_Load;
    }

    private void SetBindings()
    {
        //инициализируем
        _blNumbers = new BindingList<Number>();
        //выкл.автогенерацию столбцов
        _dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        //привязываем список к DGV
        _dataGridView.DataSource = _blNumbers;
        //привязки к колонкам
        _columnId.DataPropertyName = nameof(Number.Id);
        _columnInput.DataPropertyName = nameof(Number.InputValue);
        _columnOutput.DataPropertyName = nameof(Number.OutputValue);
    }

    private void FormMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //получаем числа
        var data = new DataContext();
        var nums = data.GetNumbers();
        //отображаем их
        nums.ForEach(_blNumbers.Add);
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _button.Enabled = false;
        var fibService = new FibService();

        try
        {
            foreach (Number number in _blNumbers)
            {
                //считаем число фибоначчи
                int result = await fibService.GetFibNumberAsync(number.InputValue);
                //отображаем его
                number.OutputValue = result;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _button.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

А это, на всякий случай, код подсчета чисел.

```
class FibService
{
    internal async Task<int> GetFibNumberAsync(int inputValue)
    {
        await Task.Delay(100);
        if (inputValue <= 1) return 1;

        return await GetFibNumberAsync(inputValue - 2) + await GetFibNumberAsync(inputValue - 1);
    }
}
```