# Вид ячеек DataGridView C#

Tags: c#

Есть код:

```
private void RiskChartLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ass_column = new DataGridViewColumn();
    ass_column.HeaderText = "Название"; // не работает
    ass_column.ReadOnly = true;
    ass_column.Frozen = true; // не работает
    ass_column.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
    dataGridView.Columns["0"].DefaultCellStyle
        .Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter; // не работает
    ... 

    dataGridView.AutoResizeColumns();   
    dataGridView.AutoResizeRows();
    dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter; // не работает 
    dataGridView.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left);


    dataGridView.AllowUserToAddRows = false;


    DataClass dc = new DataClass(); 
    BindingList<Data> data = new BindingList<Data>();
    ...
    dataGridView.DataSource = data;
}
```

Читал [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-4.8), но так и не нашел ошибку.

Есть еще момент. Так как есть привязка к данным, вычитываемым из файла, поля столбцам (`header`-ам, которые не корректные) присваиваються соответственно полям класса (`Data`). Я правильно понимаю причину некорректного, с моей точки зрения, отображения названий столбцов?

Я так понимаю, после коррекции ошибок можно будет создать метод для конфигурации вида полей (не вызывать для каждого столбца отдельно `.HeaderText`, `.ReadOnly`...)?
Да, вопросов несколько, но все связаны с форматированием вида выводимых данных.

Comment: А почему вы решили, что`ass_column.HeaderText = "Название"; // не работает`? И зачем себя мучить созданием колонок в коде, если это можно сделать в дизайнере?

Comment: Не работает, потому что запускал код и сам видел. А почему в коде, а не в дизайнере - видел пример на каком-то сайте. Я ведь только начинаю разбираться. Сначала пусть так работает. позже - оптимизация и красота.

Comment: И разве это плохой тон, если создание полей происходит при вызове обработчика `Load`?

Comment: Создайте колонки в дизайнере, а потом посмотрите [этот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1046183/222542) как сделать привязки к DGV и колонкам.

Comment: Тон здесь не причем, а есть здравый смысл по эффективному использованию своего времени и усилий.